# Accessing a remote MS Access database from PHP 5.3 / IIS7

Tags: iis-7

I am trying to connect to an ms access database that is in our company network.I have installed **IIS7** and **PHP 5.3** .For that I  have copied the database from the remote computer to my PC and it works fine.But I don't want to copy the database every time.So,I need to connect to that database remotely in PHP. I have not find any simple way.

For locally access the database ,i have configured
`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools\system DSN` and add the database path.

```
$conn=odbc_connect("dbname","" ,"");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Some newlines would be appreciated

Comment: plz improve formatting